# align image on image button android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the alignment feature ContentVertical Alignment found in ios for the android image button. It would be easier to use setGravity() however, image button does not support this method. Is there a way to work around this somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) attribute.